# How add the disabled attribute based on condition in .NET

Tags: html, attributes, .net-core

I am trying to make a view that can be editable or not depending on how it is accessed, and I wrote the following code:

```
var isDisabled = "";
if (!ViewBag.isEditable)
{
    isDisabled = "disabled";
}

...  

<input class="form-control" asp-for="something" disabled="@isDisabled" />
```

I thought this could work but apparently the only valid way for an input to not be disabled is to not have the disabled attribute, `disabled=""` still disables it (which is honestly dumb).

How can I work around this? Can I add the attribute in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

One of the quick way is pass the attribute as text. In case it is not editable it will be empty string so no affect. Example

```
       isDisabled = "disabled=\"disabled\"";

      <input class="form-control" asp-for="something" @isDisabled />
```

I am assuming that you are putting the isDisabled field in your view bag like this

```
        ViewBag.isDisabled = isDisabled
```

Comment: The problem is @isDisabled is viewed as a whole attribute not as C# code inserted. I tried that as well before asking.

Comment: Actually isDisabled is just a local variable in the view. Why would I put it in ViewBag?